# Google Sheet columns comparison several conditions

Tags: google-sheets

I need to compare columns **E** and **F**
The result should be in column **L**

`=SI(E2=F2; "Oui"; "Non")`

`SI(OU(E2="";E2=0); "")`

I don't know how to merge the two above formulas?

If the cell is empty or equal 0, nothing should be displayed in cell **L2**, if `E2=F2` it should say "Oui" otherwise "Non"

Also if **F2** is empty **L2** should be empty too...

[image]

Comment: `=SI(OU(E2="";E2=0); "";SI(E2=F2; "Oui"; "Non"))`?

Comment: Thanks I edited my question, your formula helped to see  that I forgot something

Comment: `=SI(OU(E2="";E2=0;F2=""); "";SI(E2=F2; "Oui"; "Non"))`

Comment: if you don't use Excel, please don't tag with Excel. The two are very different, even though they share some functionality.

Comment: sorry I've been told it was 90% similar so...

Comment: @marie, I don't think you have to check for `F2`. If the logic is that `E2` equals `F2` **and** you have the rule that `E2` can't be empty string nor `0` then that would imply that `F2` also can't be an empty string nor `0`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use arrayformula in L1, in FR notation

```
={"Comparaison MP";arrayformula(if(F2:F="";;if(E2:E=F2:F;"oui";"non")))}
```

[image]